# how to change an image by clicking a button in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the image when you hover over the first list item but this code is not working...................

```
<div class="first_add">
    <img id="main_image" src="images/11.png"  width="500px" height="300px"/>
    <ul class="first_add_options_list">
        <li class="first_add_options_list_1">
            <a id="hello" class="first_add_options_list" href="#">Discount 10%</a>
        </li>
        <li class="first_add_options_list_2">    
            <a class="first_add_options_list" href="#">Discount 20%</a>
        </li>
        <li class="first_add_options_list_3">
            <a class="first_add_options_list" href="#">Discount 40%</a>
        </li>
        <li class="first_add_options_list_4">
            <a class="first_add_options_list" href="#">Discount 50%</a>
        </li>    
    </ul>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#hello").mouseover(function() {
                /* Act on the event */
                $("#main_image").attr('src', 'images/12.png');
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Where you have `#hello` element in your code?

Comment: there is no change in my image

Comment: Your event is not fired because (I guess) there is no hello id in your html

Comment: i did add a hello id but still its  the same problem

Comment: @Mayur: see my answer below, there is working example too. Have you linked jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By seeing to your code, you are beginner. Please check this steps.

1. First of all you do not have your **#hello** and **.first_add_options_list_1** and a last just check whether you have *jquery cdn* or downloaded file is in the right path .. because this is one of the mistake a beginner does

You can add this to your code as

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this event will trigger when you hover the *hello* element (that doesn't exist on your document), you need to correct the id (main_image maybe?)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main_image").mouseover(function() {
        /* Act on the event */
        $("#main_image").attr('src', 'images/12.png');
    });
});
```

Comment: id="hello" is supposed to be assigned to anchor tag in first list item .. i did it already still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, instead of

```
 $("#hello").mouseover(function() {
```

You should be using

```
 $(".first_add_options_list_1").mouseover(function() {
```

Hope it Works

Answer (score 0):

The `#` sign can't be in `id` attribute.

The correct HTML is

```
<a id="hello" class="first_add_options_list" href="#">Discount 10%</a>
```

not

```
<a id="#hello" class="first_add_options_list" href="#">Discount 10%</a>
```

If you need to return the `11.png` back when you went away with mouse, you `hover` instead.

```
<img id="main_image" src="http://placehold.it/500x300"  width="500" height="300"/>
<ul class="first_add_options_list">
    <li class="first_add_options_list_1">
        <a id="hello" class="first_add_options_list" href="#">Discount 10%</a>
    </li>
    <li class="first_add_options_list_2">    
        <a class="first_add_options_list" href="#">Discount 20%</a>
    </li>
    <li class="first_add_options_list_3">
        <a class="first_add_options_list" href="#">Discount 40%</a>
    </li>
   <li class="first_add_options_list_4">
        <a class="first_add_options_list" href="#">Discount 50%</a>
    </li>    
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hello").hover(function() {
        $("#main_image").attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/499x299');
    }, function() {
        $("#main_image").attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/500x300');
    });
});
```

See the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4aykkwcy/